Player friendships database design
I'm trying to understand the best approach when storing player friendships in a MySQL database. It boils down to either one of these two "methods".
Method A - One shared row per friendship, with a structure like:
CREATE TABLE `player_friendships` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `origin_player_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `target_player_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `player_friendships_origin_player_id_foreign` (`origin_player_id`),
  KEY `player_friendships_target_player_id_foreign` (`target_player_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_friendships_origin_player_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`origin_player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_friendships_target_player_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`target_player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Method B - One row each player of a friendship with a structure like:
CREATE TABLE `player_friendships` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `target_player_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `player_friendships_player_id_foreign` (`origin_player_id`),
  KEY `player_friendships_target_player_id_foreign` (`target_player_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_friendships_player_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_friendships_target_player_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`target_player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Things to consider

With the two rows, you wont have to use OR operators or extra work to distinquish who the sender and receiver are.
With one row, less data has to be stored and maintained
With one row each player (sender & receiver) is easily known.
With two rows, one row could become out of sync (different status) to the matching.


I do not see the difference between your options. The only point is one column name which is not structural difference.

If you want to obtain any approach then you must describe your frenship system completely. Does it is bidirectional or oriented? Does it is inheritable or not? Does it is clear p2p or it can be multipersonal? What is the frienship status? And so on..
